# Passing parameter from template's "a" to view

Tags: django, view

Here is a link in my template -

```
<a href="{% url user_profile ranking.user %}" >{{ ranking.user }}</a><br />
```

Here is view for this url:

```
def user_profile(request, u):
    return render_to_response('game/user-profile.html', {'user': u})
```

And finally - contents of user-profile.html:

```
{{ user }} - this is rendered user
```

But clicking a link leads to an error:

```
TypeError at /user_profile/
user_profile() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Can't see any mistakes, maybe you will help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because you're not looking at the relevant `urls.py`.

Comment: How you have the `urls.py`?

Comment: what is `ranking.user` evaluating to ? Looks like that evaluates to `None`